# css steps() @keyframes percentage animation

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create CSS sprite steps animation like:

```
.something {
  animation: play .8s steps(10);
}
```

but started from 50% to 80% animation time?

```
0% - animation paused;
50% - animation playing with steps(10);
80% - animation paused;
100% animation paused;
```

This is needed for sync with a second animation

Comment: Why can't you start the animation from 0% itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we don't have a lot of information, it's difficult to come with a solution, but I think I have what you need to at least be put on the right path:

You can delay an animation by adding a second time-value to the `animation`-property. I think you might want to use that and also work with `@keyframes`.

Let's say your first animation, the one this one has to sync with, is 5 seconds long, and the second animation has to run after 2 seconds for .5 seconds.

**=== OPTION 1 ===**

```
@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {
     /*first step*/
  }
  10% {
     /*second step*/
  }
  ....
  90% {
     /*ninth step*/
  }
  100% {
     /*tenth step*/
  }
}
```

In your CSS class `.something`, you want to run that animation for .5 seconds but only after 2 seconds, so you do the following:

```
.something {
   animation: animation2 .5s 2s; /*animation takes .5 seconds, starts after 2 seconds */
}
```

**=== OPTION 2 ===**

You can use `animation-iteration-count`. Combining `animation: play .8s` with a delay of 2 seconds (which I took from my own example above OPTION 1) and an iteration count of 10, the animation should run 10 times and then stop.

Your CSS might look something like this:

```
.something {
   animation: play .5s 2s; /*animation takes .5 seconds, starts after 2 seconds */
   animation-iteration-count: 10; */animation repeats 10 times, but the delay is ignored */
}

@keyframes play {
   0% {}
   ...
   100% {}
}
```

I hope this pushed you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just getting started to learn that. I think this is what I need :)

Comment: 90% is actually step number 10, so alignment is a bit harder to reason about, cf. the second parameter of steps().